# Return the array indices where values are not identical

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have two arrays A[] and B[]. e.g. A[network, HTTP, SMTP] and B[Success, Success, Success].

A consist of all service names and b is there status.

To check for identical values I used:

```
B.all? { |x| x == B[0] }
```

As first value is always be the success.

I need to check whether array `B`'s values are all identical, and if not, then return the indices where it mismatches.

I need to know an efficient way to do this.

Comment: Can you add what you have tried so far?

Comment: I used array.all? {|x| x == b[0]} to check for identical values but need to return the specific index. I am quite new to ruby so not sure which loop and method to go for

Comment: Not sure how 'efficient' this is for a big array but `array_1.each_with_index.map{|v,i| array_2.include?(v) ? nil : i }.compact`

Comment: You could do `array_2[i] == v` instead of  `array_2.include(v)` if you want it to match exactly rather than it being anywhere in the array

Comment: The question does not make sense at all. If you have array elements that are not identical to one another, which ones are supposed to be the "mismatched" ones, and which are the "matching" ones?

Comment: As @sawa says. The question reminds me of that old joke "What is the difference between a duck?"

Comment: @Jinx do you want just the first index or all indices? It would help if you could add one or mores example arrays and the expected results.

Comment: @sawa Array B is consisting the status success which will be identical for all values, In case if one of the status fails I wanted to check where the mismatch happens. Does it makes a sense

Comment: @Stefan: I am having two arrays A[] and B[] b is having all status values which is success e.g. B[success, success, success] In case if any of the status value is different than success I just wanted to figure out the index so that I can point that index to A to identify the service.

Comment: @Jinx thanks for the clarification, but that doesn't answer my question: do you just want the index of the _first_ "different" element or the indices of _all_ "different" elements?

Comment: @Stefan sorry for missing it,  I want indices of all the different elements.

Comment: @Stefan Edited the question to reflect it correctly. Thanks for your patience to understand it properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
my_array = [1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 4]
indexes = []
my_array.each_with_index do |item, index| indexes << index unless item == my_array[0] end

indexes # [3, 5]
```

Comment: Why is the answer not `[0, 1, 2, 5]` (the ones not matching `3`) or `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]` (the ones not matching `4`), or `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` (the ones not matching some other element)?

Comment: It compares against the first element, I thought it had to behave like that judging by his attempt

Comment: @LeticiaEsperon Thanks a lot above solution worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

Given an array `arr`, I assume the objective is to return the smallest index `i > 0` for which `arr[i] != arr[i-1]`.

```
arr = [1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 4]

first = arr.first    
arr.index { |i| arr[i] != first }
  #=> 3
```

`nil` is returned if the array is empty or all elements of the array are equal.

Comment: Why is the answer not `[0, 1, 2, 5]` (the ones not matching `3`) or `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]` (the ones not matching `4`), or `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` (the ones not matching some other element)?

Comment: Good pint, @sawa. I changed my interpretation of the question as indicated. That was in part becaure return the OP asks for *“the index...*”` rather than `the indices`. (I just noticed the title refers to `”indices”`. Oh, well.)  At least the question is unambiguous with my new interpretation.

Comment: @CarySwoveland If you need to have "your interpretation", it's hardly unambiguous :D

Comment: @Amadan, you got me.

Comment: Or `arr.find_index { |e| e != arr.first }` (and you don't need the `any?` check)

Comment: Thanks, @Stefan. I made the change.

Answer (score 0):

Given the array `ary = [1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 4, 4, 4]` it is not possible to tell which integer leads, but you can find the index of discontinuity:

```
ary.each.with_index.with_object([]){ |(x, idx), o| o << idx + 1 if x != ary[idx + 1] }
#=> [3, 9, 10, 13]
```

Or this where also the first element is considered as a discontinuity:

```
ary.chunk_while { |a,b| a == b }.map(&:count).inject([0]) { |x, y| x + [x.last + y] }
#=> [0, 3, 9, 10, 13]
```